# Calendar inside modalpopup won't update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar, modalpopupextender

I have a calendar inside a modalpopup.

My objectives are:

1. highlight selected date/s
2. add those date/s in list
3. Show these date/s in gridview

The code is doing objective 2 and 3 just fine. However, the dates I selected will not highlight whenever i click them. **BUT when i close the popup and open it again, the previously selected days are now highlighted.**

I tried inserting an update panel but it's still not working. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thank in advance.

ASPX code:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Calendar" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"   ChildrenAsTriggers="False" RenderMode="Inline">
  <ContentTemplate>

   <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="Black" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Times New Roman" 
                    Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="220px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" 
                    TitleFormat="Month" Width="412px" OnDayRender = "Calendar13_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar13_SelectionChanged" >

                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CC3333" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Width="1%" />                      
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <DayStyle Width="14%" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" 
                        ForeColor="#333333" Height="10pt" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="13pt" 
                        ForeColor="White" Height="14pt" />
                </asp:Calendar>
                </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

And this is my day render code:

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender

    If e.Day.IsSelected = True Then
        list_Days.Add(e.Day.[Date])
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End If

    Session("SelectedDates") = list_Days
```

And the SelectionChanged event code:

```
    Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Session("SelectedDates") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim newList As List(Of DateTime) = DirectCast(Session("SelectedDates"), List(Of DateTime))
        For Each dt As DateTime In newList
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt)
        Next
        list_Days.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of silly, but after some trials, I realized the error is in Update Panel condition. I just set it on "UpdateMode: "Always"" And it worked.